# Imputed values are showing individual frequency distribution

Tags: spss, multiple-imputation

I used SPSS to impute missing values in my dataset. After imputation I ran a frequency distribution. In the table, I see that the missing values which have been imputed are shown as separate frequency. For example, I have a variable, CAT which has 2 levels of n (1=20 and 2=20) and missing values which have been categorised as -9 (assigned as missing). Suppose if the number of missing values are 5. After imputation, In the frequency distribution, I get level 1=20, 2=20, but the imputed values are shows individual frequency like 1=1, 2=1 and so on for all 5 imputed values. I tried recoding the imputed values into same variables as 1 and 2 but they still lie as separate entities in frequency distribution and logistic regression. Can anyone help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using multiple imputation, not single imputation.  In that case, several, default 5, datasets are generated with independent draws for the missing values in each.  The datasets are treated as split files, and the distributions take that into account.  If you turn off split files and run a procedure, the results will be incorrect as it would appear that you have much more data than you really do.  But treated properly, you get a final set of results that correctly represent the distribution of the missing values.